# Plot string values into time series

Tags: r

I just have a file with date, time and a string as value and I'd like to plot both values AOSL/AOSR in a time series. I want to see in the plot the different times that the values change. Is there any way to do it?

```
2012/07/02 06:35:49.551 AOSL
2012/07/02 06:35:50.048 AOSR
2012/01/26 01:37:27.691 AOSR
2012/01/26 01:37:27.847 AOSL
2012/01/10 08:32:49.578 AOSR
2012/01/10 08:32:49.832 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:00.480 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:02.507 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:04.565 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:07.605 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:12.641 AOSL
2012/01/14 00:02:55.001 AOSR
2012/01/14 00:02:57.026 AOSR
2012/01/14 00:02:59.062 AOSR
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan your data into a data frame (this is the most fiddly step)

   You may want to transform it into csv using perl or sed.

   `perl magic`

   `mydata=read.csv("mydata.csv")`
2. transform the date column into `as.POSIXct`

   `mydata$date=as.POSIXct(mydata$date)`
3. plot the data, using plot (or ggplot as below)

   `qplot(data=mydata,,color=type,x=date,y=type)`

By the way, I plotted it and it looks pretty boring - what is AOSL - the filename or the contents?

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, really seems very easy. Can I have the time in the x-axis?

Comment: The AOSL are events that they have to be reported at the same time,

Comment: It does have time on the x axis; can you explain what you mean? Do you want time modulo 24h?

Comment: I tried and I have an error: mydata$date=as.POSIXct(mydata[,1]) qplot(data=mydata,x=mydata$date,mydata[,3]) and error came out Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get? What does your csv and data frame look like?

Comment: I changed to a new data set with the valeu=ALERTHANDLER, and the new the data looks like; 2012-02-06,05:28:48.855733,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-09,07:06:16.829694,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-09,07:09:45.144085,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-10,10:47:19.351474,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-17,00:55:41.368384,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-27,02:55:55.555494,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-27,03:54:45.194325,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-27,06:46:03.118040,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-27,06:54:19.866041,ALERTHANDLER
2012-02-27,11:35:17.393159,ALERTHANDLER
the data looks like:

Comment: Out it in your question so we can see the formatting.  Also show me your data frame - using dput.